# How to display two times from date/time column

Tags: visualforce, datetime, formatting

I have two date/time fields which hold the duration of an event (i.e. start time = 11/11/14 12:00, end time = 11/11/14 18:00)

I would like to display this as 12:00 - 18:00 on my force.com page, how can I do this via `outputText`?

**EDIT**
This is the code I am currently using:

**visualforce**

```
<apex:page showheader="false" controller="force_NewsController" title="News Archive" >
<apex:composition template="{!$Site.Template}">
<apex:define name="body">  
...
            <apex:form id="pgBlock">
            <apex:repeat value="{!newsitems}" var="article" id="theRepeat">
...
                                <apex:outputText value="{!article.Event_Date_Start__c}" />
                                <apex:outputText value="{0,date,HH:mm } - {1,date,HH:mm }">
                                    <apex:param value="{!article.Event_Date_Start__c}" /> 
                                    <apex:param value="{!article.Event_Date_End__c}" />
                                </apex:outputText>
...
```

**controller**

```
public with sharing class force_NewsController {
    public list<News__c> lstItem {get;set;}
    public map<id,string> newsmap{get;set;}

...


    public list<News__c> getNewsItems(){
        lstItem = new list<News__c>();

        String category = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('cat');
        String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Title__C, Content__c, Publish_Date__c, Category__c, Event_Date_Start__c, Event_Date_End__c, ';
        query += '(Select Id, Name, LastModifiedDate From Attachments Order By LastModifiedDate DESC) ';
        query += 'FROM News__c ';

        lstItem = Database.query(query);
        return lstItem;
    }

...
```

I have checked to make sure the view and field level security allow the profile to view the data also but I am still unable to view the data.

Comment: Have you any code showing what you have tried already using [apex:outputText](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm)?

Comment: ... and if not [How to format a date in VisualForce?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516549/how-to-format-a-date-in-visualforce) should get you started.

Comment: @BarCotter I have included the code I currently have, which is not working at the minute.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Can you add more information as to whats happening?

Comment: @BarCotter I've added some more info as requested

Comment: You need to include both the controller code and VisualForce as well.

Comment: Updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,HH:mm } - {1,date,HH:mm }">
         <apex:param value="{!article.Event_Date_Start__c}" /> 
         <apex:param value="{!article.Event_Date_END__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are having two time fields called starttime and endtime, you can create a string variable in your controller to hold the duration.

```
String duration = starttime.format('h:mm a')+ ' - ' + endtime.format('h:mm a');
```

You can call the variable in your visualforce page.

```
<apex:outputText value="{!duration}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this !

```
 <apex:outputText value="{0,time,HH:mm }">
                  <apex:param value="YOUR DATE TIME FIELD" /> 
 </apex:outputText>
```

The below link would help you out with the different formatting options 
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputText.htm